# What MIN/MAX values will work with both ZonedDateTime and Instant.toEpochMilli?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I want to use MIN/MAX time values that can convert between `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant.toEpochMilli()`, to be used as sentinel values for a filter/query.

I tried:

```
OffsetDateTime.MIN.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
OffsetDateTime.MAX.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

but I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow

    at java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:892)
    at java.time.Instant.toEpochMilli(Instant.java:1237)
```

And then I tried this:

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.MIN, ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.MAX, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

but then I get this exception:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -1000000001

    at java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidIntValue(ValueRange.java:330)
    at java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidIntValue(ChronoField.java:722)
    at java.time.LocalDate.ofEpochDay(LocalDate.java:341)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(LocalDateTime.java:422)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.create(ZonedDateTime.java:456)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ZonedDateTime.java:409)
```

I also tried 'Z' `ZoneId`:

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.MIN, ZoneId.of("Z"))
```

but that returns the same exception as the last one.

Finally I tried the following, and it seems to work:

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.EPOCH, ZoneId.of("Z"));
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.EPOCH.plusMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE), ZoneId.of("Z"));
```

Is that the best solution?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Instant.EPOCH` is equivalent to `1970-01-01T00:00Z`, so I'm not sure if it's a good candidate for a minimum value (it depends on your needs, of course - if all your dates are after 1970, then it would be fine).

Converting `Instant.MIN` and `Instant.MAX` to `ZonedDateTime` doesn't work all the time because depending on the offset, the fields can be set to values beyond boundaries (like happened with the year, in your case).

If you want far distant dates that can be converted to `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant`, you don't need to use the built-in MIN/MAX constants, because they use very far dates (from years like -1000000000 to 1000000000), and the equivalent **epoch milli** values for such far dates are much greater (or lower) than the limits of a `long` value.

As you need to use `toEpochMilli()` and it returns a `long`, you must stay between the limits of a `long` value:

```
Instant minInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MIN_VALUE);
Instant maxInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.MAX_VALUE);
ZonedDateTime minZonedDateTime = minInstant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime maxZonedDateTime = maxInstant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

The respective values are:

> minInstant=-292275055-05-16T16:47:04.192Z
>   maxInstant=+292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z
>   minZonedDateTime=-292275055-05-16T16:47:04.192Z
>   maxZonedDateTime=+292278994-08-17T07:12:55.807Z

And the respective values for epoch milli:

```
System.out.println("minInstant millis=" + minInstant.toEpochMilli());
System.out.println("maxInstant millis=" + maxInstant.toEpochMilli());
```

> minInstant millis=-9223372036854775808
>   maxInstant millis=9223372036854775807

I used `ZoneOffset.UTC` instead of some specific timezone, because those dates are so far in the past/future, that a few hours offset won't make much difference. And they would all be equivalent to the same millis instant anyway.

You could also convert the `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime` using `atOffset` method (such as `minInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`).

---

**Notes**:

- instead of `ZoneId.of("Z")`, you can use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Actually, if you check `ZoneId.of("Z").equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)`, the result is `true`.
  Even `ZoneId.of("Z") == ZoneOffset.UTC` is also `true`, so both are really the same thing.
- depending on the values of your query, you don't need to use such extreme far dates. You could set the minimum to year 1900 and the maximum to 2900, for example. It all depends on your dataset. But using the approach above will be fine, if your database can handle such big values for the year.

Comment: also worth noting how far your dates range. All cases considered this could mean either before 1970 or also after the epoch's overflow (I had a case with date ranges 100+ years, you can't use a ms epoch for that)

Comment: Thanks @Hugo. Simple and brilliant. Totally makes sense now to use Long.MIN_VALUE/MAX_VALUE.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help! Indeed, using Long min and max values gives you a good range (more than 200 million years, enough for most cases, I suppose).